# Function that will not return 0

Tags: function, math, formula

I am writing a formula which to use as a decay multiplier on a given value. 
The problem is the following : I have a window of processing - days lets say 10, this window is computed every day anew. I need to decay a certain parameter with a factor reflecting the days that an id is present. Currently what I do is `(previousWinSize-(start of the current window-start of the previous window))/previousWinSize`
In this case if my previous window size is 10 and the difference in the days of processing is two (10-2)/10 which gives me 0.8 to multiply my variable by and respectively decay .2 of it. 
However if I have a 3 day window and again 2 days of difference (3-2)/3 I get value close to 0 which cuts more than I would like to. 
I am looking for a formula that would scale better when the numbers are small and would not produce a huge decay factor.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I feel like this might be a better one for the math stack exchange:
https://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend making use of a sigmoid function e.g.

[image]

You can take the output of your function i.e. returns a number between 0 and 1 based on the difference of days of processing and feed it into the sigmoid. If you set up the a (slope) and b (inflection point) parameters properly you can for example, ensure that the lowest decay multiplier you get is ~0.5 when your original equation returns a number close to 0.

I've graphed the example I stated above here:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nqemuexjhg
(This is based on: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rna4aqta0c)

I think you do have two edge cases with this method though. When your equation returns 0 the sigmoid isn't exactly going to give you 0.5 (which you may not even want to begin with), you'll end up getting something that's close to 0.5. In this scenario what you may start to see is your values drifting if you keep applying the sigmoid. The same is true for when your equation returns 1. After putting it through the sigmoid you won't get 1, you'll get something close to 1.

What I think I'd do in such a scenario is have some sort of check before the sigmoid gets applied
e.g.

```
if(x == 0)
    y = 0;
else if(x == 1)
    y = 1;
else
    y = sigmoid(x);
```

Sources / Possible further reading:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Comment: If it's of any interest I used this to render the equation:
http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php